# XSS and Content Security Policy

Tags: php, xss, htmlspecialchars, content-security-policy

From reading [XSS (Cross Site Scripting) Prevention Cheat Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_%28Cross_Site_Scripting%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet), I'm aware of what context-aware escaping is.

In some of my other projects, I've used [Zend_Escaper](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2) but I'm wondering if it is sufficient to use [`htmlspecialchars()`](https://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) to prevent XSS if I have enabled Content Security Policy without allowing [`unsafe-inline`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/CSP/CSP_policy_directives#Keywords) for JavaScript (script) and CSS (style). The way I see it, this gets rid of the JS and CSS contexts within the PHP file itself.

Assume that I don't need to output untrusted HTML data, only data *in HTML* and *in HTML attributes*.

I'd really like to stay away from templating frameworks like Twig and Smarty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. CSP is not supported by all browsers yet. And many use older browsers. CSP is at the moment a good bonus for those who use decent browsers and you can get warnings from the report policy. But not something you can rely on.

If you only have users with CSP enabled browsers, CSP should be safe against XSS with htmlspecialchars in php and escaping all output made by javascript templates for all output if you set the policies correct. That means both unsafe-inline and unsafe-eval must not be allowed. You should also restrict the hosts to those you know you load resources from and you trust. Only use https for your site and any other site you load resources from, and use [HTTP Strict Transport Security](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security) to avoid [Man In The Middle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack) attacks.

Only allow access to iframe hosts on pages which use that host in an iframe.

Reports with report-uri is also a must to see if your site has had any potential attacks or will have problems for non-CSP enabled browsers.

More info [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/38028/49885) and [here](http://blog.sendsafely.com/post/42277333593/using-content-security-policy-to-prevent-cross-site).

Comment: Ok but what about for browsers that do support CSP?

Comment: Woo, this it thst first I ever heard about `report-uri` … sounds like a little dangerous as a concept, because it surely will invite “DDoS” attacks by flooding a site owner with fraudulent reports leading to spam sites or simply to generate extra (manual) effort for checking these reports …

Comment: `report-url` is indeed awful and does flood site owners, but it's not because of attacks, it's because of poorly written browser plugins. Some plugins can individually generate hundreds of warnings that are legitimate, but the fault of the plugin rather than anything a site owner can control.